# WCF Transactions don't work

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have problem with using transactions in WCF service. I would like my app to behave like this: client starts editing some data that is placed in database. After he press "Edit" button the transaction starts and last till he end editing and press "Accept" button. Then the transaction ends. The problem is when he doesn't press "Accept" and exit application. The transaction is still on and the only reasonable solution is to set transaction timeout. Where should I put information about timeout to make service aware that the transaction have to finish after some time?

I tried to add an attribute `[ServiceBehavior(TransactionTimeout="00:01:00")]`, but service become inaccessible for client after that. Adding `<machineTimeout "00:01:00">` to app.config ends same way...

The message in detail:

> There was an error downloading
>   '`http://127.0.0.1:8732/Design_Time_Address/WebService/BSService/?wsdl'`.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it `127.0.0.1:8732` Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   '`http://127.0.0.1:8732/Design_Time_Address/WebService/BSService/?wsdl`'
>   There was no endpoint listening at
>   '`http://127.0.0.1:8732/Design_Time_Address/WebService/BSService/?wsdl`'
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. Unable to connect to the remote server.

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with transactions?

Answer (score 0):

We kept WCF transactions rather simple. We created individual create/modify methods for individual tables. Then we added a 'composit' function in the service that started a transaction (with db command), did individual tables insert/update, then either committed or rolled back the transaction. The transaction results were reported by to the client.

This allowed the client to collect data and apply business rules, calling the transaction function in the service did the true database transactional work using the db's built in transactional processing.

Just an idea.

Comment: I was thinking about sth like this:
In service three methods OpenTransaction(), CommitTransaction() and RollbackTransaction(). When I start editing data I call OpenTransaction() and my database become closed for any other manipulations.
DbTransactions did the job, but I was unable to set timeout for this type of transation (or maybe I just didn't figured it out).
Using TransactionScope doesn't seem to be a solution in this problem...
Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: You have to use the same DB connection object throughout the life of the transaction, that's why we did transaction in one service call.

Comment: OK lets put it this way... I am using DbTransaction class to keep information about current transaction. It works fine and do the job if there is more than one instance of app runnig. Question is: **how to set timeout?**

Comment: That's at the Command level:  mTransactionSQLCommand.CommandTimeout = intCommandTimeOut

Comment: Your answer seems to be a solution to my problem, but I cannot find anything like `mTransactionSQLCommand.CommandTimeout` . Do I need some assemblie or sth? And where should I put it? Just in code where I start transaction?

Comment: You mean sth like this: `DbCommand command = new DbCommand();
command = entity.Connection.CreateCommand();
command.Transaction = entity.Connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
command.CommandTimeout = 5;`
Same problem as before...

Comment: I think the only way is to change `entity.Connection.ConnectionTimeout`, but this field is read only. Btw by default its set to 30 seconds, but I can wait forever and the transaction is still in open state... I have no ideas left...

Answer (score 0):

mTransactionConnection, mTransaction, and mTransactionSQLCommandare private properties in the class, open the connection, start the transaction, do work, commit/rollback, close transaction. But the instance of this object must live throughout the transaction.

```
     Public Function StartTransaction() As Boolean
        Dim result As Boolean = False

        mTransactionConnection = New SqlConnection(_ConnectionString)
        mTransactionConnection.Open()
        mTransaction = mTransactionConnection.BeginTransaction()

        result = True

        Return result

    End Function

    Public Function RunSQL(ByVal strSQL As String) As Integer

        Dim intReturn As Integer = 0

        Dim objSQLConnection As SqlConnection
        Dim objSQLCommand As SqlCommand

        objSQLConnection = New SqlConnection(_ConnectionString)
        objSQLCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, objSQLConnection)

        objSQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        objSQLCommand.CommandTimeout = intCommandTimeOut

        'set  params

        objSQLConnection.Open()

        'execute SQL
        intReturn = objSQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        objSQLCommand.Dispose()

        objSQLConnection.Close()

        return intReturn

    End Function

    Public Sub CommitTransaction()

        mTransaction.Commit()

    End Sub

    Public Sub RollbackTransaction()

        mTransaction.Rollback()

    End Sub

    Public Sub CloseTransaction()

        mTransaction.Dispose()

        mTransactionConnection.Close()

        mTransaction = Nothing
        mTransactionConnection = Nothing

    End Sub
```